# Ruby on Rails 4 render :json with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this render expression in a Ruby on Rails 4 controller:

```
render :json => @account_preferences, :include => {:payment_methods => {:include => {:payment_type => {:only => [:id, :name]}}}}
```

Can I filter the payment_methods somehow in this expression to get only the payment_methods with state = 'Confirmed'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this conditionally in the render :json. 
But something like this would work:

```
class AccountPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :confirmed_payment_methods,-> { where state: 'Confirmed' }, class_name: 'PaymentMethod'
end
```

and call that association in your to_json

```
render :json => @account_preferences, :include => {:confirmed_payment_methods => {:include => {:payment_type => {:only => [:id, :name]}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a lot of includes and conditionals I'd recommend using jbuilder to do this kind of stuff.
Did you take a look at that?
https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

It's included in your Gemfile by default in a rails 4 project.

Comment: Thanks Sander, I will take this into account. Anyway, this time I would like to know if it´s possible to do it the way I propose.